# question about JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

If I have in my db a table called **User** with name, Id, age fields and I want to get these data and put it in a var as a JSON serialize, then I want to send it to javascript page to reform it as I want . I need to know how to put these data in a var as a JSON, how to read the data in the javascript file (how to deal with each one. for example : array[name]) !!!?

which thing is more better to deal with these data in asp.net code then send it in the javascript or to send it to the javascript and then to deal with !!? thank u :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object in .NET you can serialize it using the `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
List<User> myUsers = GetAllUsers();
string userJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myUsers);
```

This way you won't have to worry about escaping quotes or anything. Now that you have a string, you can feed that to your javascript:

```
var userJson = ... // the JSON string
var myUsers = JSON.parse(userJson);
```

---

The other way around, you may have a javascript object, that you want to pass to the server:

```
var myUsers = ... // a JS object
var userJson = JSON.stringify(myUsers);
```

If you pass the string `userJson` to the server, you can then deserialize it. If you know that the JS object corresponds entirely, in terms of property names, to a .NET object, or an array of .NET objects, say, you can deserialize it as such:

```
List<User> myUsers = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<User>>(userJson);
```

If there isn't a .NET object that can be directly mapped to the structure of the JS object, you'll have to use

```
object myUsers = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(userJson);
```

Comment: great :) but still didn't answer me about my 2nd question !!

Comment: @Rawhi: hmm... I edited my answer to include how to do things the other way around. Is that what you wanted? I'm not sure about what your question is... is it whether it's better to deal with JSON at the server side or the client side? Well, JSON is good for passing data between the client and the server, in any direction. You want to serialize it to a string at one end, pass the string to the other end, and deserialize it into an object at that end. The direction depends on what data you have where, and where you want it to go, but you generally deal with JSON in both ends.

Comment: I mean for example if I have a list of users and I want to do some decoration for each 1 (tables, css .. etc)
is it recommended to do so in the server side and then send it as a string to JS file or to send the pure data to the JS file and to do whatever I want to do in the client side !?

Comment: @Rawhi: Oh. Well JSON is built to be light weight, in order to be cheap to transfer between endpoints. HTML, on the other hand, is extremely verbose, and that effect would be lost altogether. If you're rendering the page (as in a full page reload) then I'd render tables etc with server code, but if you're in an AJAX request, for instance, I'd pass pure JSON data.

Comment: Oh, another question after I receive the data in the JS file how could I do a loop to extract the information ?!

Comment: @Rawhi: that depends very much on what your structure looks like. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/utemo3/edit

Answer (score 0):

4guysfromrolla have great articles that will teach you the ins and outs of it.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927191305/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102010-1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203220/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040809-1.aspx

you can take a look at these for your complete understanding.

besides if you just want to display results of a query ti the UI then why dont you use the gridview or repeater controls.